# Convert Json to parent,child relation structure

Tags: javascript

Want to convert JSON into parent child relation. Json consist category and sub category , match Category and push subCategory into it as child

JSON

```
    [  {
         "id": 0,
         "category": "Business Services",
          "subCategory": "Printing Services",
         "isChecked": false
        },
       {
      "id": 1,
      "category": "Business Services",
      "subCategory": "Waste Management Service",
      "isChecked": false
       },
      {
      "id": 2,
      "category": "Consumer Products Manufacture - Food and Beverage",
      "subCategory": "Alcoholic beverages",
      "isChecked": false
    },
      {
       "id": 3,
       "category": "Consumer Products Manufacture - Food and Beverage",
       "subCategory": "Cakes and Pastries",
       "isChecked": false
     },
     {
      "id": 4,
      "category": "Finance",
      "subCategory": "Finance Software and Services",
      "isChecked": false
   },
    {
    "id": 5,
    "category": "Finance",
    "subCategory": "Insurance",
    "isChecked": false
    },
  ]
```

Want to have below json form from what i have original json

```
       {category: 'Business Service',
          [ {value:'Printing Service'},{value:'Waste Management 
       service'},..]
      }, 
       { category :'Consumer products manufacture -Food and Beverage',
            [{..}...]
       }
```

Comment: please add your try. btw, [JSON](https://json.org/) is a string. you have an array of objects.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please show us what you tried so far. The community will not present you solutions without your own effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to `reduce` your input array and simply sort your output like so:

```js
const input = [{
    "id": 0,
    "category": "Business Services",
    "subCategory": "Printing Services",
    "isChecked": false
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "category": "Business Services",
    "subCategory": "Waste Management Service",
    "isChecked": false
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "category": "Consumer Products Manufacture - Food and Beverage",
    "subCategory": "Alcoholic beverages",
    "isChecked": false
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "category": "Consumer Products Manufacture - Food and Beverage",
    "subCategory": "Cakes and Pastries",
    "isChecked": false
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "category": "Finance",
    "subCategory": "Finance Software and Services",
    "isChecked": false
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "category": "Finance",
    "subCategory": "Insurance",
    "isChecked": false
  },
]

const output = input.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  if (typeof acc[cur.category] == "undefined")
    acc[cur.category] = []
  acc[cur.category].push({
    value: cur.subCategory
  });
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), collect all same categories and get a result with [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and a mapping of the wanted structure.

```js
var data = [{ id: 0, category: "Business Services", subCategory: "Printing Services", isChecked: false }, { id: 1, category: "Business Services", subCategory: "Waste Management Service", isChecked: false }, { id: 2, category: "Consumer Products Manufacture - Food and Beverage", subCategory: "Alcoholic beverages", isChecked: false }, { id: 3, category: "Consumer Products Manufacture - Food and Beverage", subCategory: "Cakes and Pastries", isChecked: false }, { id: 4, category: "Finance", subCategory: "Finance Software and Services", isChecked: false }, { id: 5, category: "Finance", subCategory: "Insurance", isChecked: false }],
    grouped = Array.from(
        data.reduce((m, { category, subCategory }) =>
            m.set(category, [...(m.get(category) || []), subCategory]), new Map),
        ([category, values]) => ({ category, subCategories: values.map(value => ({ value })) })
    );

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this:

Check if key does not exist then create the key and append value, otherwise extract
previous values and append the new one

```
const result = arr.reduce((acc, curr, i) => {
  if (!Object.keys(acc).includes(curr.category)) {
    acc = {
      ...acc,
      [curr.category]: [{ 'value': curr.subCategory }]
    }
  }
  else {
    acc[curr.category] = [...acc[curr.category], { 'value': curr.subCategory }]

  }
  return acc;

}, [])

console.log('output result', result);
```

Proof example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-answer-json-transormation2